# How to create Development version of Production database for testing in Parse

Tags: database, testing, parse-platform

I have a Parse.com database, containing user data as well as a (simple) relational data model. I'd like to create a clone of that "production" database that I could use for development and testing. I can't find anything in the docs about how to do that other than to create a new app and do a one-by-one json import of the tables, but those don't seem to get stitched together correctly, especially the Relations. Anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

just create another app which will generate the dashboard entries (including keys )

get the key values that relate to your app type ( rest OR android OR javascript ) and substitute those keyvalues(devel keys) into your call to parse.init().

that is all there is to it.

you will want to provide the keys to your builds depending on type(debug, release)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I was traveling. I think I did not phrase my question precisely enough. I know how to create a new "app". What I don't know how to do is replicate the existing *Data*. I.e. my User table, and other data my app is saving for existing users. I'd like to have a copy of the Data so I can test some migration procedures.

Comment: no 'export' util i know of but a Curl script u write yourself for each Class will do the export /import without too much trouble.